Is Microsoft Accounts chrome extension supported by Electron?
I have an electron app based on electorn v22.3.25. I would like to use Seamless SSO in a WebView of my application by log in on Microsoft 365. In order to achieve that, Chrome needs to be integrated with a plugIn called 'Microsoft Accounts'.
I tried to add this chrome extension to my Electron app following this Electorn doc: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/extensions, but without any good news. Do you have more details about this plug-in with respect to its support on Electron? Thanks.
